# How to allow Chrome (browser) to load insecure content?

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome, by default, blocks insecure content on secure pages. Is there any way to allow it to load the full content and have it ask me (like Firefox does)?  Even if it doesn't ask me and just loads it that is OK with me.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

When you visit a secure page with insecure content, a shield icon will appear at the right edge of the omnibar.

Click on the shield icon, and then click **Load anyway**, and the insecure content will be loaded.

[image]

Comment: Works for me in chrome 30.0.1599.66

Comment: doesn't work here either: there is no shield despite the message stating that I should allow safe content, this is to connect to google docs hosted at my university, strange, doesn't work on chrome/firefox , but does work on safari...

Comment: @PatrickT That may have to do with the way your university has configured its servers. It is possible for a HTTPS server to specify, for instance, strict transport security, in which case insecure content would never be loaded.

Comment: I see thanks Michael. Yes, I suspect our IT have messed up, wouldn't be the first time ... The page has the message `In your address bar > click a small icon > select load unsafe script in the message > done > refresh the web page.` but no icon ... Never mind, I can use Safari. Note to others: try Safari, perhaps a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Just a fyi for future finders, this is currently broken in Chrome 34. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333308

Comment: How to return into 'disallow mode'?

Comment: The icon is gone in chrome 53

Comment: This no longer works in Chrome 53. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I don't think you can do this anymore. You'll need to fix your website instead.

Comment: I have faced the same issue several times and found if we logged out from chrome than unsafe script and images were being loaded.

Comment: Any option to do the same in the Android mobile browser?

Comment: Still works on Chrome 71, just click on the icon and then "load unsafe scripts"

Answer (score 16):

Windows 8:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-running-insecure-content`

OSX 10.11:

`'/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' --allow-running-insecure-content`

Comment: Funktioniert nicht unter Version 87.0.4280.141 (Official Build) (x86_64) und MacOS Catalina

Answer (score 9):

To allow insecure content on individual sites within Chrome, click on the lock icon in the URL bar, then click 'Site settings'.
[image: A site's lock icon in Chrome omnibar]

There you will see a list of various permissions the page has. Choose 'Allow' next to 'Insecure content'.
[image: Permissions list]

Answer (score 7):

on a mac, you can create an AppleScript application in AppleScript editor with following contents:

```
do shell script "'/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' --allow-running-insecure-content > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

when you save it as an application, you can assign chrome icon to it :)

Comment: how does this work?

Comment: @PatrickT this launches Chrome with the command line flag to run the unsafe content. If it doesn't make sense, try a different solution since always loading unsafe content can literally be unsafe.

Comment: simple and works for me!  I needed this to make LiveReload work with localhost-https app

Comment: Version 47. this is not working anymore. please test and update the answer kindly. i tested myself and it failed in OSX also in Windows 8.

Answer (score 7):

Inspect page, and open console and type:

```
sendCommand(SecurityInterstitialCommandId.CMD_PROCEED)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you get to the blocked page you can also just type "thisisunsafe" and it will let you use the insecure page

Edit: mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274659/when-you-use-badidea-or-thisisunsafe-to-bypass-a-chrome-certificate-hsts-err

Comment: Please post a reference link for this.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach is to create a dedicated insecure instance via a shortcut with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-running-insecure-content. This way you don't have to be annoyed on allowing all the time in your browser and can run a separate instance at the same time as a regular instance of Chrome while working within a site. Check out the tutorial at: [https://1337admin.org/windows/windows-7/allow-chrome-to-load-insecure-content/](http://www.1337admin.org/windows/windows-7/allow-chrome-to-load-insecure-content/)

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).

Comment: @bwDraco — And wouldn't you know, the link has gone offline! ‍♂️

Comment: Fixed the typo.