# How to "load unsafe script" in google chrome frame

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

Since a week or two one of our web applications is having issues.

Because in our corporate environment only IE8 and Chrome latest version are allowed, 
the web application was made to work in Chrome and uses Google Chrome Frame when running in IE8.

Everything worked well until two weeks back. All of a sudden one of the actions doesn't work anymore because it calls to http://www.ourapplication.com from the https://www.ourapplication.com domain. (This is treated as cross-browser scripting)

In chrome we get to see a little shield in the browser where we then can allow to "load unsafe script" and the application still works. IN IE8 (actually hijacked by the Google Chrome Frame cuckoo's egg) I don't find any way to allow this unsafe script.

Is there a way?

Comment: encrypt everything.

Comment: Is the issue here about what is being passed more than the browser?

Comment: @DaveRook The underlying issue is known (http call from https >> XSS), but will take time to get resolved by the IT department. In the meantime we have a workaround in Chrome to "load unsafe script" (http://superuser.com/questions/487748)  but we don't seem to be able to do something similar in Google Chrome Frame running inside IE8. Is something similar possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% what I asked for, but it's possible to add the commandline switch *--allow-running-insecure-content* to the Google Chrome Frame command line by following [this blog post](http://tech.royans.net/2013/01/chrome-frame-how-to-add-command-line.html) .

You just have to create the following registry key :       `Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\AdditionalLaunchParameters`

and add here the string *--allow-running-insecure-content*

***Note***: While you *can* do that, it's VERY UNSAFE so if anyone knows how the get the "load unsafe script" prompt in Google Chrome Frame, please do share this.

For more on the AdditionalLaunchParameters registry key see [http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AdditionalLaunchParameters)