# Make Chrome automatically load insecure content for specific pages/websites

Tags: google-chrome, security

Is it possible to have Chrome load content for **specific web pages**?

I have this page that I go to all the time and I am tired of clicking on the shield each time(to load anyway).
I don't want to have it load insecure content for all websites as it is not recommended.

This page: ["This page has insecure content."](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?hl=en) from Google does not not answer my question as I want a solution that automatically loads insecure content ***only for specific pages***.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow Chrome (browser) to load insecure content?](http://superuser.com/questions/487748/how-to-allow-chrome-browser-to-load-insecure-content)

Comment: NOT a duplicate -- this is asking if there is some sort of whitelist.  That answer only provides an all-or-nothing solution.

Comment: @Wingman4l7: that is right , a whitelist.