# How to always allow insecure connection for a certain url in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, security, ssl, certificate

For internal usage, we have a system using a self-signed insecure SSL certificate, making Chrome warn me on each session:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from
>   log.hive.stage.dreamlines.nl (for example, passwords, messages, or
>   credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

I always have to click `Advanced` and then `Proceed to my-custom-site.foo (unsafe)`. I don't want to do this on every session. I know about the risks, I always want to trust an insecure certificate for a specific domain.

How can disable the warning for a specific URL in Chrome? I don't want to allow all insecure content, it should be a whitelist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/742089/make-chrome-automatically-load-insecure-content-for-specific-pages-websites?lq=1 even though it didn't get any answer yet.

Comment: I won't tell you how to disable the warning.  Just place the self-signed insecure but trusted certificate into the operating system's certificate store.  You won't get the warning at that point.  This is much safer then disabling the warning.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't want to trust that certificate in all cases, only in the context of surfing to a specific page.

Comment: Chrome is designed in such a way that warning cannot be disabled.  We are lucky we can even click continue, and continue to the page, to be honest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress Google Chrome's "Your Connection is Not Private" for specific Address?](http://superuser.com/questions/960850/suppress-google-chromes-your-connection-is-not-private-for-specific-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***IF*** you know what you are doing, then in chrome you can add the 'insecure' domain under `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` — **DO NOT** do this with domains that you do not control, or which you are unsure about.

> <sup>The only valid use case for doing this is for development when you need to whitelist your own domain or IP with a self-signed cert, etc.</sup>

Comment: Perfect, this is the quick whitelist I approach I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

To allow insecure connection for a certain URL, you need to import their site certificate into your keychain and make it trusted for your HTTPS/SSL connection, so Chrome can understand that. To make it work for all web addresses, you need to import Root certificate instead.

In Chrome basically you've to click on padlock icon, then in Connection tab/Certificate Information find your insecure issuer and download CRT file which therefore can be imported into your system keychain.

[image: GitHub - The identity of this website has not been verified. Server's certificate is not trusted.]

or use the following command to save that file:

```
ex +'/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/p' <(echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443) -scq > file.crt
```

Then open the file and find the option to import the certificate and make it trusted for HTTPS/SSL.

For example on OS X you can double-click on the file or drag and drop in your Keychain Access, so it'll appear in login/Certificates. Then double-click on the imported certificated and make it *Always Trust* for SSL.