# Chrome for Windows 8 Blocks Insecure Content with No Option to Allow

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, ssl

My company uses an idiotic security product that basically reissues certs for secure websites, which causes security warnings in the browser for any SSL-based URLs. Usually the browser will present the warning and then give you the option to proceed if you want to, but Chrome seems to be notorious about deciding to protect you against your will and will often give you no option to continue at all.

A current example is https://ssl.gstatic.com, which pretty much holds all the static resources for every Google property. If I try to go to Google Analytics, for example, all I get is a blank page, because it literally can't load anything to do anything. This one domain, in particular, provides no option to load anyways and gives some nonsense error message about it using HSTS, which from what I can tell is nothing different than any other secure website.

Anyways, how can I force Chrome to actually allow me to proceed since I know this is perfectly safe. I found other similar questions to this one and associated answers, but they all seem to be outdated. I can't find any current info for the latest Chrome running on Windows 8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow Chrome (browser) to load insecure content?](http://superuser.com/questions/487748/how-to-allow-chrome-browser-to-load-insecure-content)

Comment: If you'd like newer/different answers to the existing question, please post [a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) and some comments on the original, instead of asking again.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007  I am not sure that old question applies here.  Chrome uses Certificate pinning for the Google owned domains.  I don't think you can simply bypass it using the generic methods.

Comment: @Zoredache Seems the same to me.  Example -- From this question: "This one domain, in particular, provides no option to load anyways and gives some nonsense error message about it using _HSTS_" - comment on accepted answer at possible dupe: "It is possible for a HTTPS server to specify, for instance, _strict transport security_, in which case insecure content would never be loaded". I'll pass it back to you to suggest why it's _not_ the same question... :)

Comment: The possible dupe is a perfect example of old questions that no longer apply. Theres no shield icon any more and the command line directive has been removed. The third answer there is for Mac OS X, so also not relevant.