# Force Chrome to always load 'unsafe scripts'

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I've followed the solution here - [How to allow Chrome (browser) to load insecure content?](https://superuser.com/questions/487748/how-to-allow-chrome-browser-to-load-insecure-content/487824#487824) - but Chrome continues to complain that "This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources", requiring me to load the scripts manually, refresh the page and go through this process each time I access the page (or similar pages).

Is there some other way I can disable this aspect of Chrome?

Answer (score 3):

Change your Chrome shortcut to this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-running-insecure-content
```

Another site showed the command parameter inside the quotes; that is wrong. It must be outside the quotes just like above. I am using it now to play Farmville, which was what was giving me a problem in Chrome.

Comment: How to set this within a Chromebook?

Comment: Its not working in Version 47, please check.

Comment: No longer working for new version of chrome and chromium (I tried on v65 and v70)