# Google chrome - Allow insecure content for one domain automatically

Tags: google-chrome

I have an AJAX request from a https site to http URL. Chrome thus blocks it as loading "Mixed Content".

I know how to force it to load unsafe scrips as in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/487748/how-to-allow-chrome-browser-to-load-insecure-content).

But, the script that I wrote will be run using Tampermonkey on the client side. How can I automatically enable the same without clicking on the shield icon and choosing **Load anyway** option each time... maybe through whitelisting or a setting?

Also, please note that I don't want Chrome to force loading the unsafe scripts as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/878238/force-chrome-to-always-load-unsafe-scripts)